# ckeditor not loading on element generated via ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using custom form and generating form elements with ajax call but textarea is not loaded with ckeditor. Here is my code:

ajax code:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reg_arz_ajax2.php",
    data: "book="+book_arzyabi,
    dataType : "html",
    success: function(response){

        $('#resp').html(response);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        //On error, we alert user
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open");

});
```

ajax response is:

```
   '<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="fname" name="fname" rows="10" >test</textarea>';
```

html code:

```
  <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../include/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../include/ckeditor/sample.js" ></script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form>
 <fieldset>
 <label for="name">Name</label>
 <div id="resp" ></div>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please help me for resolve problem.

Comment: Does it throw any errors? What happens?

Comment: no, display only textarea without eceditor toolbars.

Comment: Paste the code that converts your textareas to eceditor textareas.

Comment: ckeditor.replace('fname'); and $("#fname").ckeditor(); both doesn't work.

Comment: try this http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/editor-not-visible-pages-loaded-ajax

Answer (score 2):

Insert these lines:

```
ckeditor.replace('#fname'); // ADD THIS
$('#fname').ckeditor(); // ADD THIS
```

Your code should look like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "reg_arz_ajax2.php",
data: "book="+book_arzyabi,
dataType : "html",
success: function(response){

    $('#resp').html(response);
    ckeditor.replace('#fname'); // ADD THIS
    $('#fname').ckeditor(); // ADD THIS
},
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    //On error, we alert user
    alert(thrownError);
}
});

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open");

});
```

Comment: do you get any errors? (if you check firebug for example)

Answer (score 2):

for me having only this line worked:

```
ckeditor.replace('#fname');
```

and the following line needs to be REMOVED:

```
$('#fname').ckeditor(); // this does NOT work
```

also note, that `ckeditor` needs to be in caps, so:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('#fname');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add only `CKEDITOR.replace('fname');` instead. The **#** is not necessary. Also, you do not have to add:

```
$('#fname').ckeditor();
```

Make sure it's uppercase throughout, eg CKEDITOR not ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

don't add ckeditor.replace('#fname');
you have to add $('#fname').ckeditor();
and in my project is works

Answer (score 0):

Edit this lines:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'fname' );
```

Your code should look like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "reg_arz_ajax2.php",
data: "book="+book_arzyabi,
dataType : "html",
success: function(response){

    $('#resp').html(response);
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'fname' ); //this line should be changed like this
    $('#fname').ckeditor();
},
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    //On error, we alert user
    alert(thrownError);
}
});

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open");

});
```