# Yii2 CKeditor not initialized when requested via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor, yii2

I am trying to add a from with a `CKeditor` widget imbedded via an `AJAX` request. The request itself works fine and returns the general partial view as I want it. Except for the `Ckeditor` widget, a normal textbox is return instead.

When the item is added to the group and the page is reloaded, the same partialView is being rendered (in a foreach with all group-items) and this time the `CKeditor` is nicely in place.

Posted my controller, initialization of the `CKeditor` and `Scipt with AJAX` request below. (The `CKeditor` is inlcuded in the `_ContentItemHtml` view)

I have taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757388/ckeditor-not-loading-on-element-generated-via-ajax-call), but I cannot call any `CKeditor` functions from `JS` since it is loaded as a widget.

**Controller Action**

```
public function actionCreateHtml($contentitemgroupid)
{
    $model = new ContentItemHtml();
    if (isset(Yii::$app->request->post()['ContentItemHtml'])) {
        $item = Yii::$app->request->post()['ContentItemHtml'];
        $model->contentitemgroupid = $contentitemgroupid;
        $model->title = $item['title'];
        $model->body = $item['body'];
        $model->save();
        // return $this->redirect(['edit', 'id' => $model->contentitemgroupid]);
    }
    else
        return $this->renderPartial('_ContentItemHtml', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

**Active form in view:**

```
echo $form->field($model, 'body')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'preset' => 'custom',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'height' => 200,
        'toolbarGroups' => [
        ['name' => 'basicstyles', 'groups' => ['basicstyles', 'cleanup']],
        ['name' => 'paragraph', 'groups' => ['templates', 'list']],
        ['name' => 'mode']]
    ]])->label(false);
```

**Script.js**

```
$('#addNewContentItem').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = 'create-' + $('#itemSelector').val().toLowerCase() + '?contentitemgroupid=' + $('#itemSelector').attr('contentitemgroupid');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    success: function(res) {
      $('.contentItemsManager').append('<div class="ContentItemContainer row">' + res + '</div>');
      AddSaveEventListener();
      AddSaveMediafileEventListener();
      AddRemoveEventListener();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If I understand you right the ckeditor.js is already included in the main template? After adding your widget you must initialize the ckeditor again. To do so first check if ckeditor.js is already included inside your main template and maybe post the generated html for the widget so we can help figuring out the right jQuery selector

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753143/yii-ajaxlink-in-partial/6754862#6754862

Comment: @hyde I'm load `CKeditor` via the Yii2 framework, this handles all the javascript. I'm not able to access this.

Comment: @topher added the parameters to the return `return $this->renderPartial('_ContentItemHtml', ['model' => $model],false,true);` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I just noticed you are using yii2 not yii 1. In that case try using [renderAjax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753143/yii-ajaxlink-in-partial/6754862#6754862) instead of renderPartial

Comment: That fixed it, will post it in an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`renderAjax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753143/yii-ajaxlink-in-partial/6754862#6754862) instead of `renderPartial`. From the docs:

> [renderAjax] Renders a view in response to an AJAX request.
>
> This method is similar to renderPartial() except that it will inject into the rendering result with JS/CSS scripts and files which are registered with the view. For this reason, you should use this method instead of renderPartial() to render a view to respond to an AJAX request.